# React component setting the onClick of it's child ... how to make it work for all kinds of children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that wraps another, and sets the child's `onClick` like this:

```
class OutstandingActionForm extends Component {
   render() {
        return (
            <div className="outstanding-actions">
                {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {onClick : this.openForm})}
```

It basically lets the parent (`OutstandingActionForm`) open a modal if the child (whatever it is) is clicked, and separates the appearance of the click-target from the behaviour of the thing that opens.

This works fine if the child is an `<img>`:

```
           <OutstandingActionForm actions={this.props.actions}>
                <img src={'/assets/notification.jpg'} className="notification-icon"/>
            </OutstandingActionForm>
```

In this case, the `OutstandingActionForm` opens if the `notification.jpg` `<img>` is clicked.

However, for some reason it doesn't work if the child component is itself a react component:

```
             <OutstandingActionForm actions={this.props.actions}>
                <OutstandingActionsSummary/>
            </OutstandingActionForm>
```

Even if OustandingActionSummary is itself just an image:

```
class OutstandingActionsSummary extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
              <img src={'/assets/notification.jpg'} className="notification-icon"/>
    )
}
```

Why is this so?   How could I achieve the same when wrapping a react component as when wrapping the native `<img>` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<img>` knows how to use `onClick`. But `<OutstandingActionsSummary>` doesn't! In the implementation of `<OutstandingActionsSummary>`, you have to specify how to use the property. It should look like:

```
class OutstandingActionsSummary extends Component {
    render() {
        return <img onClick={this.props.onClick}/>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class OutstandingActionsSummary extends Component {
    static defaultProps ={
        onClick:function(){}
    }
    render() {
        return (
              <img onClick={()=>this.props.onClick()} src={'/assets/notification.jpg'} className="notification-icon"/>
    )
}
```

OutstandingActionsSummary doesnot support onClick,add it.

Comment: How do I give a component a method like `onClick`, that it's parent can set?

Answer (score 0):

In OutstandingActionForm use only {this.props.children} and attach click handler on OutstandingActionsSummary and call its parent OutstandingActionForm to process.